# A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: Invalid head of packet (0x00)

Tags: arduino, serial-port, ide, esp32, packet

I tried all the google solutions, It seems like RST button doesn't actually reset. Just red led blinking all the time, and no serial output or anything I'm working on Windows 10, ESP32 Dev Module ,on COM4 ,Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS), 240MHz (WiFi/BT), QIO, 80MHz, 4MB (32Mb), 115200, None.
I tried with different esp it works

```
Sketch uses 204738 bytes (15%) of program 
storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 13416 bytes (4%) of 
dynamic memory, leaving 314264 bytes for 
local 
variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
esptool.py v3.0-dev
Serial port COM4
Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____
```

`

```
   A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect 
   to ESP32: Invalid head of packet (0x00)
```

Answer (score 3):

I normally upload at 921600. Your settings look perfect, it is working very well for me. Try the following -

1. If the Serial pins(Rx/Tx) are connected anywhere, disconnect/unplug them.
2. Keep the boot button on hold while it is trying to connect.
3. Change the USB port. If you are using hardware debuggers, zadig can mess things up.

I have faced similar issues, the above mentioned ones have always solved it. Choosing wrong board also results in this issue, I tried ESP-01, ESP-03 or other smaller boards with this setting and faced this. So make sure you are using exactly the ESP32 dev module and not anything else.

Comment: The board was working correctly, but I connected to RX and then disconnected it, and this problem occurred. I tried all the ways I mentioned earlier, and still the same error

Comment: Thanks a million: the TX pin was the culprit in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, turns out I didn't have the proper USB driver installed.

[SiLabs CP2104 Driver](https://www.silabs.com/developers/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers)

Hope this helps someone in the future.